# Increase efficiency in comparing one field with multiple collection Mongodb Jdbc

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, jdbc

Hi , I have one SQL query i'm trying to implement it in MongoDB using MongoJava driver Jdbc [2.10]. My sql query is,

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.x = table2.x and 
table1.y IN ( somevalue ) AND  table2.y IN (somevalue)
```

In MongoDB i have Table1 collection and Table2 collection. Using Jdbc i created two object to access two collection. Consider i have 1 lack record in each collection. If i try to compare each single document value with another collection, it takes 1 lack * 1 lack comparison. ?? after that i want to match it with 'y' value ??

Can any one suggest me how can i efficiently convert this query to MongoDB jdbc query ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mongdb doesn't support joins like that so you'd need to do multiple queries.  something like this maybe:

`db.collection1.distinct( 'id', { y: { $in: [...] } } )`

then take those IDs and do another $in query against collection2.

Though, I have to ask why you'd have a table without unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

With classic RDBMS, you modeled your base and then you write your queries.

With MongoDB, it's tend to be the opposite : you list your use cases, i.e. access pattern and you model your data according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Mongo Java driver does not support SQL or the JDBC API.  MongoDB does not support joins.  If you want to use SQL, there is a JDBC driver available: [JDBC Driver for MongoDB](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php).  You can also avoid joins by combining the two collections into one using nesting.